# Object expressions and error FS0419: 'base' values may only be used to make direct calls to the base implementations of overridden members

Tags: inheritance, compiler-errors, f#, overriding, fsunit

The error in the title is vague but [googling it](https://www.google.com/search?q=error%20FS0419%3A%20'base'%20values%20may%20only%20be%20used%20to%20make%20direct%20calls%20to%20the%20base%20implementations%20of%20overridden%20members) gives presently two hits on SO and five altogether (suggesting it is a rare beast, so don't expect too many visits here ;). I expect this question to be sixth in that list :p.

[Kvb's answer in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5847202) suggests that the error text is misleading and is raised if you call base from within a closure, but that doesn't always seem the case, as this works:

```
// in a closure, but no FS0419
let myObj = fun foo ->
    { new obj() with override this.ToString() = base.ToString() + foo}
```

But this fails (the simplest way I found to exemplify the issue):

```
// not in a closure, but raises FS0419
let myObj = 
    { new obj() with override this.ToString() = () |> base.ToString }
```

I was using object expressions instead of type declarations with inheritance, and I tried to create a new FsUnit constraint by building a custom NUnit constraint. Here's a simplified version that shows the issue I was seeing:

```
let EndsWithIgnoreWhitespaceContraint expectedResult = 
    { new EndsWithConstraint(expectedResult) with 
        override __.ApplyTo<'T> (actual: 'T) =
            let actual = box actual
            if actual :? string then 
                actual :?> string
                |> fun s -> if isNull s then String.Empty else s
                |> fun s -> s.Trim()

                // error FS0419: 'base' values may only be used to make direct
                // calls to the base implementations of overridden members
                |> base.ApplyTo 
            else
                exn "String expected .. bla bla..." |> raise        }

// make it available to FsUnit's syntax style (overriding existing endWith)
let endWith = EndsWithIgnoreWhitespaceContraint

// using it:
"  hello world  " |> should endWith "world"
```

Now, it is obviously not necessary to know FsUnit to see this behavior. But it took me a night and a day to realize I was duped, in fact I didn't see it until I was writing this question on SO.

Turns out that this works:

Instead of `x |> base.SomeMethod` write `base.SomeMethod x`.

I find this surprising. Not sure it is a bug or a feature. But since the `|>` operator is inlined (I tested it with a different operator) and it doesn't create a new function (like `>>` does), I don't see why this error is raised.

In fact, I don't see any semantic difference between `f a` and `a |> f` (apart from precedence rules and the like). So why the error? What rule am I breaking?

---

One final thought, kvb wrote "`base`cannot be called from a closure... curried members create a closure automatically", this suggests this would be wrong, but it compiles just fine:

```
let myObj foo bar = 
    { new obj() with override this.ToString() = base.ToString() + foo + bar}
```

Does anybody know of precisely what causes, or not causes, this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you misunderstood the answer that "*base cannot be used in a closure*". It was meant to refer to a closure that *captures the base itself* - it is the capturing that prevents this from working, not the closure as such. In your `{ new obj }` example, `base` is not captured by any closures. The whole object is captured, but `base` is only directly used within the `ToString` method.

To illustrate, try this:

```
let myObj = 
    { new obj() with override this.ToString() = (fun() -> base.ToString())()}
```

This code won't compile, because `base` is being captured by the closure `fun() -> base.ToString()`.

Secondly, using an object method as a function does not work "directly" as one might expect, because .NET methods are represented differently from F# functions. Instead, when faced with something like `let x = obj.M`, the compiler will treat it as `let x = fun a -> obj.M(a)` - that is, wrap it in a closure.

To illustrate, try this:

```
let myObj = 
    { new obj() with 
      override this.ToString() = 
        let f = base.ToString  // Error here
        f()
    }
```

See where this is going? :-)

When you pipe into an object method, the compiler has to create that closure, and then pass it to the pipe operator. To illustrate, try this:

```
let myObj = 
    { new obj() with 
      override this.ToString() = 
        () |> base.ToString  // Same error
    }
```

Comment: Interestingly, your last example I added to my question only moments before you posted this ;). I wasn't aware that often an implicit closure is created when calling to an object's methods. But when I compile `x |> f`, it is compiled into `f a` (iirc), so following your story this error is caused by the semantic difference (which I didn't notice). In `x |> obj.f`, the compiler does not know (or isn't optimized to know) whether `obj.f` will end in a closure, like in an implicit `f' = obj.f; f' a`, or an explicit (by virtue of inlining) `obj.f a`.

Comment: In the end, everything gets optimized away, so there is no performance overhead from piping into a method. However, error checking happens before optimization, and so piping into a method of `base` is not allowed.

Comment: So, we conclude here as an aside, that `a |> f`, even inlined, is almost, _but not quite_ the same as `f a` (before optimizing). Interesting lesson, for sure!

Comment: All these edge cases ultimately come from having to live in the .NET infrastructure. This is why it's advisable to avoid classes when possible.

Comment: Yes, that seems a logical conclusion. Though, as kvb noted, it may just as well be a limitation imposed by simply not having enough resources to fix it idiomatically, when he said _" there's no fundamental limitation preventing base members from being callable from within closures"_ (in the comments). Arguably similar to some polymorphism not being allowed, or child classes. Not an idiomatic limitation, but a limit imposed by deeming it not worth the effort to fix (and I can sympathize with that).

Comment: Yes, of course there is not. The `base` value can perfectly well be captured in a closure in principle, it just has to be captured a little differently than normal values, which is why it needs special effort to implement.